# Mount /data partition without losing data

Tags: data-recovery, twrp, mount

In some new models, when installing a custom recovery, `/data` partition won't mount. To fix that I need to wipe partition. How can I fix without losing data?

Answer (score 0):

Android M added support for **`/data` encryption**, and Android N made it mandatory.

Old custom recoveries' having trouble mounting `/data` is primarily because they aren't capable of decrypting it. Newer recoveries will prompt for a password (or pattern) before they attempt to access `/data` (or nothing if you don't have a locked lockscreen).

Solution: Give up that recovery and get another one, but this time make sure the recovery you're installing **supports `/data` decryption** (like TWRP).

Comment: I'm using the latest version of twrp but it won't ask me for a password.  My data partition shows as 0mb and acess to the partition is denied.  My device is soft bricked so only have access to the download and the recovery at the moment.